# What part of speech is "taking" here? What rule of grammar it follows?

Tags: parts-of-speech

"He stepped forward, a corona of light taking shape around him."

Word "taking" here is definitely not a gerund, but it still doesn't have "to be" verb attached to it. What is it then exactly, and which rules are being applied here?

Comment: It's a participle; See **https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/present-participle/** or google **participle**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *He stepped forward,* [*a corona of light taking shape around him*].

"Taking" is a present participle verb in the bracketed non-finite clause. The clause has progressive aspectuality: it is the equivalent of the finite clause "a corona of light was taking shape around him".

Non-finite clauses are tenseless, often enabling us to append them to main clauses as adjunts without the need to start a new sentence, as is the case in your example.

The non-finite clause functions here as a supplementary adjunct, set apart by punctuation and a slight pause in speech. Since it contains a subject ("a corona of light"), it is known as an **absolute** construction, one that is subordinate in form with no syntactic link to the main clause.

The natural interpretation here is probably temporal: *He stepped forward whilst a corona of* *light took shape around him*.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is  equal to:

> **He stepped forward, a corona of light (which was )taking shape around him**

Here** taking**is part of the defining relative clause.,

**Taking** is a present participle here..

you may use similar structures:

**The man standing at the gate is my father**

**The man who is standing at the gate is my father**